# HTTPS Loop redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Anyone help me to stop redirection in HTTP to https in WordPress site.

Here is scenario

http://example.com
301 Moved Permanently
https://example.com/
301 Moved Permanently
https://www.example.com/
200 OK

Comment: You may need to share what's in our .htaccess first

Comment: Why does this have the google-analytics tag ?

Comment: @chrisChen Here is rewrite message<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Hi @EikePierstorff
The above-mentioned error will be showing the google analytics only

Comment: add your `.htaccess` file into your question with markup. it's hard to read it from comments

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand correctly, this is your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Aod you want to redirect page from http://example.com and https://example.com - both to https://www.example.com - is this correct?

If so, use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

What this does, it redirects the page from non-www to www and then it forces https.